# Failed to deserialize user out of session

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I want to be able to delete users from my database, but as soon as I do it, if the user is logged in and the user tries to refresh the page I get the following error:
Error: Failed to deserialize user out of session

Here's my code:

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1`, [id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    return done(null, results.rows[0]);
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create some condition to handle if there is not a record in your database.

Here is an example. You may need to adjust the `if` condition based on what you are expecting to be returned from the database if a record doesn't exist.

```js
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1`, [id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (results.rows[0]) {
      return done(null, results.rows[0]);
    } else {
      return done(null, false)
    }

  });
});
}
```